# Update multiple values in WHERE MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I want to update multiple itemIDs with the same status. I know that this is imposible with mysql_query but I can't figure out a way to get this working.

```
     $upd = "UPDATE booking SET status='$status' WHERE itemID='$itemID', '$itemID2'";
     $retval = mysql_query($upd, $con);
```

Note: The itemIDs are inputted by user in prev page like this

```
     $itemID= $_POST["itemID"];
     $itemID2= $_POST["itemID2"];
```

Comment: `where itemid in (itemid1, itemid2)` will do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use IN clause as like:

```
WHERE itemId in ('$itemID', '$itemID2');
```

instead of `WHERE itemID='$itemID', '$itemID2'`

Comment: Works like a charm and it was a so easy fix, thanks1 :D

Answer (score 1):

Use `IN`

```
$upd = "UPDATE booking SET status='$status' WHERE itemID IN ('$itemID', '$itemID2')";
```